# PHP Calculating total hours not getting accurate answer

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to calculate the total number of a person based on when they `in`, `break`, `resume`, and `out`.

I have these data:

```
$data[0]['type'] = 'in';
$data[0]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 08:01:52';

$data[1]['type'] = 'break';
$data[1]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 12:00:40';

$data[2]['type'] = 'resume';
$data[2]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 13:00:39';

$data[3]['type'] = 'break';
$data[3]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:29:21';

$data[4]['type'] = 'resume';
$data[4]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:29:50';

$data[5]['type'] = 'break';
$data[5]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:29:53';

$data[6]['type'] = 'resume';
$data[6]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:30:00';

$data[7]['type'] = 'break';
$data[7]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:30:09';

$data[8]['type'] = 'resume';
$data[8]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 14:30:12';

$data[9]['type'] = 'out';
$data[9]['created_at'] = '2019-02-01 18:01:51';

$hours = 0;
$minutes = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $d){
    $d['created_at'] = str_replace(" ","T",$d['created_at']);
    if($d['type'] == 'in' || $d['type'] == 'resume'){
        $workingTime = new DateTime($d['created_at']);
    }

    if($d['type'] == 'break' || $d['type'] == 'out'){
        $date2 = new DateTime($d['created_at']);
        $diff = $date2->diff($workingTime);
        $tempHours = $diff->h;

        $tempHours = $tempHours + ($diff->days*24);
        $hours += $tempHours;

        $tempMin = $diff->i;
        $minutes  += $tempMin;
    }
}

if($minutes == 60){
    $hours += 1;
    echo $hours. " hours and 00 minutes";
}else if($minutes > 60){
    $hours = $hours + floor($minutes/60);
    $minutes = $minutes % 60;
    echo $hours. " hours and ".$minutes." minutes";
}else{
    echo $hours. " hours and ".$minutes." minutes";
}
```

The total that I am getting is: `8 hours and 57 minutes` , **while the correct answer should be** `08 hour and 59 minutes and 21 seconds`.

I think the reason why I am not getting the correct answer it's because in my code I do not include the seconds in the calculation.

Can someone help me in getting the correct answer by including the seconds in the calculation.

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

By the way, the reason why i know that the correct answer is `08 hour and 59 minutes and 21 seconds` because of this website: https://www.calculator.net/time-calculator.html

I get the sum of the difference of all of these:

```
$a = break - in
$b = break - resume
$c = out - resume
Then: $total_time = $a + $b + $c
```

Let me know if this is unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the actual code of the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It processes each element of the array, setting the work start and end time when we see `in`; setting a period start every time we see `in` or `resume`; and adding the period length to the day's work time every time we see `out` or `break`. Finally we take the difference between the day's start time and the time which we have created by adding all the periods, which gives us the whole day's work time.

```
foreach ($data as $event) {
    $this_time = new DateTime($event['created_at']);
    switch ($event['type']) {
        case 'in':
            $work_start_time = clone $this_time;
            $work_end_time = clone $this_time;
        case 'resume':
            $start_time = $this_time;
            break;
        case 'break':
        case 'out':
            $work_end_time->add($start_time->diff($this_time));
            break;
    }
}
$working_hours = $work_start_time->diff($work_end_time);
echo $working_hours->format('%H hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Output:

```
08 hours, 59 minutes, 21 seconds
```

**Note**

If a shift can be longer than a day, you will need to change the last line to this:

```
echo $working_hours->format('%a days, %H hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Or if you need to have only hours, not days, use this:

```
echo $working_hours->days*24+$working_hours->h . $working_hours->format(' hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BXlEE)

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for this. I am currently AFK atm. I will check this one out once i get back to my computer. BTW, does this support if the date range is not the same with the start date? Example Feb 01 - Feb 02 ? I am asking brcause there will be times that a person's shift will cross over to the next day, like a night shift.Thanks.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower as long as the events are in the order `in`, (`break`, `resume`)*, `out` then the actual date values don't matter (if they go backwards time will be taken off!). If the shift goes overnight this will be taken care of because all the variables are full dates.

Comment: i tried changing the IN date in to 2019-01-31 woth the same time, but the output is still the same.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower see my edit. That will deal with shifts longer than a day

Comment: Hey Nick, this looks perfect. I will test it properly. I will mark this as the correct answer after.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower I've updated the demo link with the additions for long shifts. Have fun! :-)

Comment: This looks perfect! Thanks, Nick. I will accept this as an answer. Cheers! :-)